# Hadoop Pig - Removing csv header

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

My csv files have header in the first line. Loading them into pig create a mess on any subsequent functions (like SUM). As of today I first apply a filter on the loaded data to remove the rows containing the headers :

```
affaires    = load 'affaires.csv'   using PigStorage(',') as (NU_AFFA:chararray,    date:chararray) ;
affaires    = filter affaires by date matches '../../..';
```

I think it is a bit stupid as a method, and I am wondering either there is a way to tell pig not to load the first line of the csv, like a "as_header" boolean parameter to the load function. 
I don't see it on the doc. What would be a best practice ? How do you usually deal with that ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CSVExcelStorage` loader support to skip the header row, so instead of `PigStorage`  use `CSVExcelStorage`. Download `piggybank.jar` and try this option.

**Sample example**

**input.csv**

```
Name,Age,Location
a,10,chennai
b,20,banglore
```

**PigScript:(With SKIP_INPUT_HEADER option)**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';
A  = LOAD 'input.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER');
DUMP A;
```

**Output:**

```
(a,10,chennai)
(b,20,banglore)
```

**Reference:**
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html

Answer (score 0):

**Another simple option for Pig 0.9, without using SKIP_INPUT_HEADER option can be done as follows:**

**Input file(input.txt)**

**input.txt**

```
Name,Age,Location
a,10,chennai
b,20,banglore
```

**PigScript:(Without using SKIP_INPUT_HEADER option, as this option is not available in Pig 0.9)**

```
register '<Your location>/piggybank.jar';
d_with_headers  = LOAD 'input.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage() AS (name:chararray, age:long, location:chararray);

d = FILTER places_with_headers BY name!='Name';

dump d;
```

**Output:**

```
(a,10,chennai)
(b,20,banglore)
```